# Exchange calendar and meeting workspace integration within SharePoint 2010

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, meeting-workspace

I'm unsure if this exists, wondering if anyone has gotten it to work. I am looking for functionality like this.

- User creates a team meeting in outlook
- User adds a meeting workspace to their SharePoint 2010 team site and adds other attendees; they then send out the meeting invites.

Now this is what I would like SharePoint to do, without user input. Both the Meeting workspace and a calendar are already part of the site.

- Meeting workspace item is created
- Meeting is added to team site calendar listing all of the attendees

Now if the calendar is pulling information either from the meeting workspace or from an exchange calendar, it really doesn't matter. I just want them to display the same information as they should be linked in some manner. But I am unsure of how to do this. Heck, it might already be there in SharePoint and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is now out of the box solution for that. You could write custom code to update the calendar information each time the attendee-list gets modified.